# android - RecyclerView add new items move recycle to top of list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I add some items to my `RecyclerView` when it scrolls and gets to the end of the `RecyclerView`  . this is my code:

```
rc_products.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (ViewType == ViewTypes.Grid) {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    if (taskrunning != null && taskrunning == false && loadmore) {
                        page = page + 1;
                        getProducts(page);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

when It reaches the end of `RecyclerView`  it gets some new data and add new items to my adapter , this is the code runs afterward :

```
if (productAdaper == null) {
    productAdaper = new MyAdapter2(Productha.this, items_products);
    ScaleInAnimationAdapter scaldeAdapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(productAdaper);
    scaldeAdapter.setDuration(300);
    rc_products.setAdapter(scaldeAdapter);
} else {
    productAdaper.addAll(items_products);
}
```

it works fine and it adds new items to my `RecyclerView`  either but it scrolls all the way up to the top of the `RecyclerView` when it adds new items.

How can I prevent it to go up and make it stay where it was when it adds new data ?

Comment: Can  we see the code for the productAdapter?

Comment: It is not clear how do you add new items to the `RecyclerView`. Do you do that in ` `getProducts(page)` ?

Comment: yes , getProducts(page) gets new datas